# Write DataFrame to parquet on HDFS partitioned by multiple columns with dynamic partitionOverwriteMode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I have a dataframe which I want to save in parquet format to HDFS. I'd like to partition it by **multiple** columns.

When I'm writing data to HDFS - directory itself and only _SUCCESS file in it are created, but no data. I use `partitionOverwriteMode=dynamic` and `overwrite` as save mode. By the time I execute code path does not exist. If I change save mode to `append` then it works fine.
I also tried to write to local file system. In that case, both modes work correctly. 
If only 1 partition column specified, then it works fine too.

Any ideas on how I can make *overwrite* works with multi-columns partitioning? Any tips appreciated. Thanks!

Code sample:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf

data = [
    {'country': 'DE', 'fk_imported_at': '20191212', 'user_id': 15},
    {'country': 'DE', 'fk_imported_at': '20191212', 'user_id': 14},
    {'country': 'US', 'fk_imported_at': '20191212', 'user_id': 12},
    {'country': 'US', 'fk_imported_at': '20191212', 'user_id': 13},
    {'country': 'DE', 'fk_imported_at': '20191213', 'user_id': 4},
    {'country': 'DE', 'fk_imported_at': '20191213', 'user_id': 2},
    {'country': 'US', 'fk_imported_at': '20191213', 'user_id': 1},
]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf = SparkConf()
    conf.set('spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode', 'dynamic')

    spark = (
        SparkSession
        .builder
        .config(conf=conf)
        .appName('test partitioning')
        .enableHiveSupport()
        .getOrCreate()
    )

    df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
    df.show()
    df.repartition(1).write.parquet('/tmp/spark_save_mode', 'overwrite', ['fk_imported_at', 'country'])

    spark.stop()
```

I'm submitting application in client mode. Spark version is 2.3.0.
Hadoop version is 2.6.0

Comment: I had no such issue writing in python on databricks and readong back via scala. all data there.

Comment: @thebluephantom I suspect it can be something related to hadoop version we are using. It's cloudera distribution

Comment: Should not matter

Comment: progress here yet?

Comment: nope, I'm thinking I'll do a workaround to check whether a directory exists and change save mode before write. The other option is to not use multi column partitioning

Comment: well i would talk to support as i have no such issue... good luck, let us know what it was when u find out.

Comment: @thebluephantom could you tell me please what's the value for `spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class` on your cluster? I just tried EMR and it works. There is different from hadoop commiter class

Comment: It goes to dbfs. Will look later

Comment: Are you using S3?

Comment: ('spark.hadoop.spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class',
  'org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.DirectParquetOutputCommitter'),

Comment: @thebluephantom no, we use HDFS, but migrating to s3. As far as I know, DirectParquetOutputCommitter was deprecated. I'll check it out tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: I saw that, but that is what came up from Databricks using 2.4.

Comment: The outcome was?

Comment: I answered on this in the past elsewhere, think answer is correct.

Comment: it works but not with default parquet output committer shipped with hadoop 2.6 and 2.7. I didn't try anything >2.7. Works fine on EMR and Databricks because they use different commiters

Comment: so you can answer your own question now?

Comment: Whether this issue got resolved. Because I am also getting same issue with multiple columns. Not only for .parquet() , but also for .csv() as well. Its writing blank output if multiple columns are provided on .partitionBy() clause. With Single partition column , its working fine.